# Tikz: itemize under process

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I am trying to add a itemization below each process step (arrow) but somehow it is displacing my process! Can anybody give me a hint?
I have also tried the `smartdiagram` package but it does not seem to have itemization integrated into its package...

```
\documentclass[15pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
arrow/.style={
  draw,
  minimum height=1.6cm,
  inner sep=1em,
  shape=signal,
  signal from=west,
  signal to=east,
  signal pointer angle=110,
  text centered, 
 }
 }

\node[arrow, align = left](a) {fdsafsasa- \\ fdsasdfa};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = 1.9cm] (b) {testtest-  \\ testtest};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = 5.28cm] (c) {test- \\ testtesttest};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = 8.65cm] (d) {test\\ testtest};
\node at (-1, -1.3) {\small - this is supposed to be my bulletpoint};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the coordinates in a `tikzpicture` is not relative to the page or text block, but only to the other things in the diagram.

When you do `\node at (-1,-1.3)`, the center of the node is placed at `(-1,-1.3)`. If you don't supply the coordinate, it's placed at `(0,0)`. So the first arrow node is placed with its center at x=0, and your bullet point node is centered at x=-1. But because the bullet point is wide, it extends much further left than x=-1, making the whole diagram wider, and thus pushing the arrows right.

That said, you might perhaps just as well use an `itemize` environment after the `tikzpicture`?

Some other things:

- Instead of using `right=Xcm` with increasing values of `X`, use `right=of a`, `right=of b`, etc. The separation can be set with the `node distance` key.
- The `enumitem` package doesn't work well with `beamer` I think, so I'd suggest not using it.
- `15pt` is not a valid class option for `beamer` I believe, so it won't do anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{
arrow/.style={
  draw,
  minimum height=1.6cm,
  inner sep=0.5em, % reduced
  shape=signal,
  signal from=west,
  signal to=east,
  signal pointer angle=110,
  text centered,
  font=\small % added
 }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1mm
]

\node[arrow, align = left](a) {fdsafsasa- \\ fdsasdfa};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = of a] (b) {testtest-  \\ testtest};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = of b] (c) {test- \\ testtesttest};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = of c] (d) {test\\ testtest};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{itemize}
\item
Bullet point
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1mm,
]

\node[arrow, align = left](a) {fdsafsasa- \\ fdsasdfa};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = of a] (b) {testtest-  \\ testtest};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = of b] (c) {test- \\ testtesttest};
\node[arrow, align = left, right = of c] (d) {test\\ testtest};

\node [right] at (-1, -1.3) {\small - this is supposed to be my bulletpoint};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much! That was exactly what I was searching for :-)